# Is Jhana Required For Awakening?

Tags: jhana, meditation-concentration

I've found this to be an interesting question with highly respected monastics falling on both sides of the answer.

Comment: Given it's a controversial topic, I'd suggest [this](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1518/why-are-jhanas-controversial) question is a better one to get a definitive answer; I'm not sure that we want questions that are so subject to controversy, do we?

Comment: Are you asking about Buddhist meditation in general or the Four Jhanas specifically? If meditation, then I suggest you update the question title. If Four Jhanas, then this is a duplicate of the following question: http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1287/in-meditation-should-one-pursue-tranquility-first-prior-to-looking-for-insight

Comment: @yuttadhammo We want, just let people state different points of view.

Comment: Then how does one choose the "best" answer without relying upon personal opinion?

Comment: Please discuss here: http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/114/questions-asking-for-an-answer-to-a-controversy

Answer (score 3):

Actually, a point that is not well understood is that, among those who follow the Pali canon, there is no controversy over whether *some* jhāna is necessary; the answer is in all cases yes. The controversy is really over *which* jhāna is necessary.

There are three types of jhāna in total:

1. **samatha-jhāna** - jhāna based on a conceptual object that, due to its conceptual nature, cannot lead to the realization of the nature of reality.

For example, in the Visuddhimagga:

> The colour should not be reviewed. The characteristic should not be
>   given attention. But rather, while not ignoring the colour, attention
>   should be given by setting the mind on the [name] concept as the most
>   outstanding mental datum, relegating the colour to the position of a
>   property of its physical support. That [conceptual state] can be
>   called by anyone he likes among the names for earth (pathavī) such as
>   “earth” (pathavī), “the Great One” (mahī), “the Friendly One”
>   (medinī), “ground” (bhūmi), “the Provider of Wealth” (vasudhā), “the
>   Bearer of Wealth” (vasudharā), etc., whichever suits his manner of
>   perception. Still “earth” is also a name that is obvious, so it can be
>   developed with the obvious one by saying “earth, earth.” It should be
>   adverted to now with eyes open, now with eyes shut. And he should go
>   on developing it in this way a hundred times, a thousand times, and
>   even more than that, until the learning sign arises.
>
> [Path of Purification, IV.29](http://static.sirimangalo.org/private/4.html)

2. **vipassana-jhāna** - jhāna based on ultimate reality that allows one to see the three characteristics and thus attain nibbana. As the Mahasi Sayadaw states:

> The tranquillity that occurs while one contemplates various phenomena is called momentary concentration, the concentration that lasts momentarily during contemplation. No insight is possible without this momentary concentration. The meditator who has no basic [samatha] jhānic experience and relies on insight meditation alone develops insight through momentary concentration and attains the noble path. This concentration for insight is not confined to a single object. The meditator practising it notes all the mental and physical phenomena that arise. However, at the moment of noting, his mind is fixed on the object and free from distraction. This is obvious to the meditator who practises effectively.
>
> http://www.aimwell.org/sallekha.html

3. **lokuttara-jhāna** - jhāna that takes a supermundane object (nibbana), and is equivalent to attaining the noble path and fruition. According to Bhante Gunaratana:

> But the four jhanas again reappear in a later stage in the development of the path, in direct association with liberating wisdom, and they are then designated the supramundane (lokuttara) jhanas. These supramundane jhanas are the levels of concentration pertaining to the four degrees of enlightenment experience called the supramundane paths (magga) and the stages of liberation resulting form them, the four fruits (phala).
>
> http://www.budsas.org/ebud/jhanas/jhanas01.htm

It is this third type of jhāna that everyone agrees is necessary. The problem is with deciding which type of jhāna the Buddha is talking about in specific contexts. Since these three types of jhāna are not enumerated in the sutta pitaka, the debate centres around whether lokiya (mundane) samatha jhāna are necessary, since that is the only type of jhāna recognized by certain Buddhists.

This too can be seen as a misunderstanding, since samatha jhāna according to those who hold that it is not necessary is not exactly the same as jhāna according to those who hold that lokiya jhāna is.

According to those who say lokiya jhāna is necessary, they seem to believe that lokiya jhāna is a practice which allows for the realization of insight, in which case it cannot be samatha jhāna as understood by those who believe that samatha jhāna cannot lead directly to insight, unless the former group actually believes that jhāna based on a conceptual object can allow for the realization of insight into reality, which I'm pretty sure is not the case.

So, the debate is really not all it is cracked up to be, unless there are people who believe meditation based on a non-real conceptual object is sufficient for attainment of understanding of reality, in which case they are in contradiction with the sutta pitaka, not to mention the abhidhamma and commentaries.

I suppose there could still be room for debate over whether samatha jhāna based on a concept must be cultivated prior to Vipassana; the yuganaddha sutta probably shows this to be false:

> Then there is the case where a monk has developed tranquillity preceded by insight. As he develops tranquillity preceded by insight, the path is born. He follows that path, develops it, pursues it. As he follows the path, developing it & pursuing it — his fetters are abandoned, his obsessions destroyed.
>
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.170.than.html

Of course for anyone actually adhering to the Theravada (I.e. the commentaries, patisambidhamagga, and abhidhamma), there isn't much room for controversy. Most of the debate is over whether to follow the existing commentaries or create one's own.

Comment: Yuttadhammo, this is really useful but could you clarify the meaning of the word "lokiya". Your answer lists three kinds of jhana -- samatha, vipassana, and lokuttara -- but then you introduce a fourth word, "lokiya", without prior mention of what it means. (I don't doubt the content of what you're saying -- just pointing out that an already good answer could be even better if you clarified this one point). Thanks!

Comment: Lokiya just means mundane - I added a parenthetical.

Comment: So of the three types, samatha is lokiya, lokuttara is not lokiya, is that right? So then what is vipassana -- lokiya or not lokiya?

Comment: On further Googling I realise that lokuttara *is* the antonym of lokiya, so me noting that "lokuttura is not lokiya" is just an empty tautology. Still, my question remains: what is Vipassana; mundane, or supramundane (I'm guessing the former)?

Comment: Yep, vipassana is mundane.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think there is a reason why the path is eightfold and not sevenfold. The *Pāḷi Canon* is full of encouragements, made by the *Buddha*, to practice *jhānas*. It would be stretching the texts a lot to say it isn't necessary. I wouldn't argue over it though.

> ‘The sage, the withdrawn chief bull,
>   the *Buddha* who awakened to *jhāna*,
>   the One of Broad Wisdom has found
>   the opening amid confinement.’
>   -[*AN 9.42, Confinement (Sambādha-suttaṃ)*](http://lirs.ru/lib/sutra/The_Numerical_Discourses_of_the_Buddha,Anguttara_Nikaya,Bodhi,2012.pdf#page=1318) & [*SN 2.7, Pañcālacaṇḍa (Pañcālacaṇḍa-suttaṃ)*](http://lirs.ru/lib/sutra/Connected_Discourses_of_the_Buddha(Samyutta_Nikaya).Vol.I.pdf#page=71)

---

> 'There's no *jhāna* for one with no discernment,
>   no discernment for one
>   with no *jhāna*.
>   But one with both *jhāna* & discernment:
>   he's on the
>   verge of Unbinding.'
>   -[*Dhp v372*](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.25.than.html#dhp-372)

Comment: Isn't one of the difficulties, though, that the word "jhāna" is used in (at least) two different ways. One -- the least common now but maybe exactly what was intended back then -- is simply "meditation". The second -- the most common today -- refers to a series of distinct states or stages of absorption *while* meditating. I'm guessing the original questioner was using it in the second form, but it's possible the Canon is using it in the first. In which case the answer is "Yes, jhana is required, but all that means is you need to meditate"??

Comment: I would say the two meanings apply since there is no contradiction between them. So I would say, "Yes, *jhāna* is required, but all that means is you need to meditate to make those stages appear in your practice."

Comment: I'm not sure that's true. I've seen many comment on how they'd been meditating for years and never experienced absorptions. Then they encountered a teacher who, or read a book that, guided them precisely, and bingo they experienced absorption. The very fact there is a debate shows there are two concepts at stake. The percentage of people who meditate seems much higher than the percentage who meditate *and* experience the absorptions. So the question still remains -- is it necessary, for awakening, to meditate to the extent that one experiences the absorptions (or at least upacara samadhi).

Comment: As I said in the answer, I wouldn't argue about it. :)

Answer (score 2):

From [SN 55.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn55.5/en/sujato):

> “Sir, the factors of stream-entry are associating with good people,
> listening to the true teaching, **proper attention**, and practicing in
> line with the teaching.”
>
> *“Sappurisasaṃsevo hi, bhante, sotāpattiyaṅgaṃ, saddhammassavanaṃ sotāpattiyaṅgaṃ, **yonisomanasikāro** sotāpattiyaṅgaṃ,
> dhammānudhammappaṭipatti sotāpattiyaṅgan”ti.*

According to the sutta above, proper attention (*yonisomanasikāra*) is required for stream entry.

It's not possible to achieve proper attention, when one is afflicted with the [five hindrances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_hindrances). In order to significantly overcome the five hindrances, one needs to have mastered at least the first jhana. You can find more info in [this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/25011/471).

To quote Ven. Dhammavuddho from that question:

> The third condition, this word - yoniso manasikara, which I translate
> as focused attention. Sometimes they say careful attention. This word
> means that when you listen to the Dhamma, you are focused on listening
> to the Dhamma. In other words, at that time, you don't have the five
> hindrances. If that is so, then you can understand the Dhamma and
> attain stream entry.
>
> So who are the people who do not have the five hindrances? In the
> suttas, it is stated by the Buddha that as long as a person has not
> attained piti and sukha which are secluded from unwholesome states,
> which are secluded from sensual pleasures, the five hindrances will
> obsess him and obsess him habitually.
>
> ... When a person has attained the first jhana, he has eliminated the
> five hindrances and the Buddha says that the five hindrances no longer
> obsess that person habitually.
>
> So there are two conditions if a person has the hindrances. Firstly,
> it obsesses your mind, it enslaves your mind. Secondly, it is
> habitual, it is very often there. ... When a person attains the first
> jhana, these hindrances reduce to a very low level. ...

In that question, Ven. Dhammavuddho claimed that instead of the first jhana, it is also possible that persons of high IQ can also achieve proper attention, although this is his personal opinion.

From this page on [Nirodha Samapatti](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/nirodha-samapatti):

> According to Vis.M. XXIII, the entering into this state takes place in
> the following way: by means of mental tranquillity (samatha) and
> insight (vipassanā) one has to pass through all the 8 absorptions one
> after the other up to the sphere of
> neither-perception-nor-non-perception and then one has to bring this
> state to an end. If, namely, according to the Vis.M., the disciple
> (Anāgāmī or Arahat) passes through the absorption merely by means of
> tranquillity, i.e. concentration, he will only attain the sphere of
> neither-perception-nor-non-perception, and then come to a standstill;
> **if, on the other hand, he proceeds only with insight, he will reach
> the fruition (phala) of Anāgāmī or Arahantship.** He, however, who by
> means of both faculties has risen from absorption to absorption and,
> having made the necessary preparations, brings the sphere of
> neither-perception-nor-non-perception to an end, such a one reaches
> the state of extinction.

So, according to the Visuddhimagga, the 8 jhanas and Nirodha Samapatti are not absolutely required for attainment of the fruition of anagami and arahat.

Comment: SukkhaVipassaka can enlighten Arahatraphala without order from 9 samapatti. This kind of people must has less 5 hindrances from his birth to enlighten in 7 years, or more than that for TanhaCarita MandaPuggala (too much hindrances who avoid to practice Jhana and no knowledge in Paticcasamuppada). **However,** most Arahanta attain 6 Abhiñña as well according to Theragatha, so I think Arahanta try to practice 9 Samapatti after enlightenment too. The same as Arahanta try to memorize Buddha's teaching which commentary commented BhandāgāikaPariyatti (Nikaya Memorizer) is duty of Arahanta directly.

Answer (score 2):

Upacara&Appana Jhana are required for TanhaCarita according to Netti, Kayagatasatisutta's &Mahasatipatthanasutta's  structure, Visuddhimagga DitthivisuddhiNiddesa.

[Netti](https://sutta.men/?rm.r.46.93...ta%E1%B9%87h%C4%81carito#hl) (my english is terrible, so please find the translation yourself):

> [81] tattha diṭṭhicarito asmiṃ sāsane pabbajito sallekhānusantatavutti bhavati sallekhe tibbagāravo. taṇhācarito asmiṃ sāsane pabbajito sikkhānusantatavutti bhavati sikkhāya tibbagāravo. diṭṭhicarito sammattaniyāmaṃ okkamanto dhammānusārī bhavati. taṇhācarito sammattaniyāmaṃ okkamanto saddhānusārī bhavati, diṭṭhicarito sukhāya paṭipadāya dandhābhiññāya khippābhiññāya ca niyyāti. taṇhācarito dukkhāya paṭipadāya dandhābhiññāya khippābhiññāya ca niyyāti.
>
> tattha kiṃkāraṇaṃ, yaṃ taṇhācarito dukkhāya paṭipadāya dandhābhiññāya khippābhiññāya ca niyyāti, tassa hi kāmā apariccattā bhavanti, so kāmehi viveciyamāno dukkhena paṭinissarati dandhañca dhammaṃ ājānāti? yo panāyaṃ diṭṭhicarito ayaṃ āditoyeva kāmehi anatthiko bhavati. so tato viveciyamāno khippañca paṭinissarati, khippañca dhammaṃ ājānāti. dukkhāpi paṭipadā duvidhā dandhābhiññā ca khippābhiññā ca. sukhāpi paṭipadā duvidhā dandhābhiññā ca khippābhiññā ca. sattāpi duvidhā mudindriyāpi tikkhindriyāpi. ye mudindriyā, te dandhañca paṭinissaranti dandhañca dhammaṃ ājānanti. ye tikkhindriyā, te khippañca paṭinissaranti, khippañca dhammaṃ ājānanti, imā catasso paṭipadā. ye hi keci niyyiṃsu vā niyyanti vā niyyissanti vā, te imāhi eva catūhi paṭipadāhi. evaṃ ariyā catukkamaggaṃ paññāpenti abudhajanasevitāya bālakantāya rattavāsiniyā nandiyā bhavataṇhāya avaṭṭanatthaṃ [āvaṭṭanatthaṃ (sī. ka.)]. ayaṃ vuccati nandiyāvaṭṭassa nayassa bhūmīti, tenāha ‘‘taṇhañca avijjampi ca samathenā’’ti.

In DesanaHara, TanhaCarita should practice 4 Satipatthana and 4 Jhana. That is compatible with KayagatasatiSutta's commentary which separate Kayanupassana into 2 parts, Samatha and Vipassana.

The structure of KayagatasatiSutta is Samatha, and MahasatipattahanaSutta is Vipassana. This is compatible with many points of MahasatipattahanaSutta's commentary.

That's why in Visuddhimagga DitthivisuddhiNiddesa:

> and the purification of consciousness, namely, the eight attainments (Upacara Jhana) together with access concentration (Appana Jhana), has also been dealt with in detail in all its aspects in the Description of Concentration, (Chs. III to XIII) stated under the heading of “consciousness”

---

Don't combine and don't separate samatha-jhāna, vipassana-jhana,  and lokuttara-jhana without deep understand in the pali canon.

Samatha-jhāna and vipassana-jhana are friends who fight together to win, become Lokuttara-Jhana, **together**.

**Balava** Vipassana-Jhana can't grow up with 5 hindrances. Samatha-jhāna can't  attain Nibbana without Understanding in the reality and 7 Anusaya. They are colleagues in the noble eightfold path.

Lokuttara-appana-jhana are them who graduated as a team, maggacittupada (**a** noble eightfold path; it is not many. It is only one team; it is "ariyo atthangiko Maggo", not "ariya atthangika magga").