# Where can i find the original text of learning the jhanas

Tags: books, scripture

I want to find the cannon text on learning the jhanas. Is there a pdf or something in english i can download? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: the path to purification i think is canonical in theravada. it would be your best bet (exhaustive), if you want to practice in that tradition, imvho. i have a print copy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In advance, the whole tipitaka is about jhāna, include sīla&vinaya.

For more focusing, see paṭisambhidāmagga.

For the summary, see [Path of Purification (Visuddhimagga)](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/PathofPurification2011.pdf).

**For more focusing, except 1st and 2nd chapter of Visuddhimagga, then all chapters, after that, is about jhāna, ārammaṇūpanijjhāna&lakkhaṇūpanijjhāna.**

Answer (score 2):

On [this page](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-samadhi/jhana.html), you can find quotes from the Pali Canon on jhanas together with their sources.

For further commentary on jhanas, please see [this page](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/gunaratana/wheel351.html).

[This question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/12/471) may also help you.

Answer (score 0):

How to reach jhana is explained in [SN 48.10](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn48/sn48.010.than.html), in the last part about concentration.

Since jhana is a state of non-thinking, how can it be reached by reading, thinking, planning & wanting?

> *There is the case where a monk, a disciple of the noble ones, making it his object to **let go** ([vossagga](https://suttacentral.net/define/vossagga)), attains concentration, attains
>   singleness of mind.*